# How to protect a column in excel against changes using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'd like to lock out some of the columns in the  for changes. To do that, I first locked out the entire file.

```
ws = wb["RFI"]
ws.protection.sheet = True
```

But then I try lock some of columns

```
for col in ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD']:
    ws[col].protection = Protection(locked=False)
```

I got

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'protection'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `worksheet['<some letter>']` what you get back is a tuple of all the cells in that column:

```
ws['A'] -> (Cell A1, Cell A2 ... Cell A<max_row>)
```

After you lock the sheet you need to iterate over the cells that you want to unlock:

```
ws = wb["RFI"]
ws.protection.sheet = True

for col in ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD']:
        for cell in ws[col]:
            cell.protection = Protection(locked=False)
```

This way your sheet will be locked but those specific columns will not be.

Comment: This is really takes a lot of time on big files. More optimal solution ?